# Setting the lead in apex:actionFunction

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, controller

I'm trying to refresh a Visualforce component like so:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="refreshFileList" reRender="fileList">
    <apex:param name="lead" value="{!lead.Id}" id="y" assignTo="{!lead}" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```

I get the dereference-null error at this point, because I need to pass the lead to the controller to get it to work properly but I don't know how to do that. My controller sets the lead like so:

```
public class AWS_S3_BrowseController {

    private Lead lead;

    public BrowseController(ApexPages.StandardController s) {
        this.lead = (Lead)s.getRecord();
    }

    public PageReference refreshFileList() {
        // do I need to re-get the lead here?
        return null;
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `action` parameter:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="refreshFileList" action="{!refreshFileList}" reRender="fileList">
    <apex:param name="lead" value="{!lead.Id}" id="y" assignTo="{!lead}" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```

The `name` parameter is used to define the JS method name, so when you're calling this `actionFunction` from JS, you call it by the name specified in the `name` parameter, but the `action` parameter is the one that determines which apex method is going to be called.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I'm still getting my null error though.

Comment: Add getter and setter methods to your lead variable in your class and make it public - `public Lead lead {get; set;}`